# Accepting partial playlists via drag & drop in Spotify App

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, spotify

I'm working on a Spotify app and built a dropzone inside my application so users can drag music onto it. It works with songs, albums, and playlists. Whenever they drag this content over, their cursor shows a green plus sign and everything works.

Whenever a user selects just a few songs from **an existing playlist**, though, the dropzone refuses to accept them. No green plus sign is shown. Nothing is transferred to the dropzone.

Any thoughts?

```
var dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropzone');
dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropzone.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    return false;
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    var droppedURI = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    // rest of code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my attempts and research (googling) it seems it's not possible at all to drop more than one link into a dropzone. I don't get the point in that so I guess it's bug. However it *is* possible to drop multiple links onto the app's icon, and at least in my case that's good enough.

How I did it:

```
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.LINKSCHANGED, function(){
    models.application.links.forEach(function(link){
        // Use your already existing logic and do whatever your want to do with the links
        // For example (assuming you already have a playlist object):
        if( (link.split('/')[3] || link.split(':')[1]) === 'track' ){
            playlist.add(link);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!